# graphite charts today's time series along with previous days' min, max, avg

Tags: charts, graphite

I'm new at Graphite and I want to do something pretty specific but I would think pretty typical at the same time.

I use Graphite to chart how a show how many messages my application handles throughout the day (from 08:30 to 16:00), charted as a time series. In order to determine whether it's an average, slow or super busy day, I would like to also show on the same chart avg, min, max values based on previous days' measurements.

I wrote a custom application that does that but Graphite seems more powerful and more scalable.

Here's a sample of what I have in mind: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33599458/monitor_chart_vm_mq_with_outliers.png

You will note the 3 yellow area charts representing from bottom to top, the min, avg and max for previous days and the red line for today.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have found my own answer, more or less: One can use a combination of the timeStack and max/average/minSeries functions as follows with the my_metric example and a time range of 60 days:
my_metric
alias(maxSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Max")
alias(averageSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Avg")
alias(minSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Min")

Comment: Congrats! Please write this answer below and mark it as valid. :)

Comment: thanks Dukebody, I didn't know I could do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own answer, more or less...
One can use a combination of the timeStack and max/average/minSeries functions as follows with the my_metric example and a time range of 60 days:

my_metric
alias(maxSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Max") alias(averageSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Avg") alias(minSeries(timeStack(my_metric,"1d",0,60)),"Min")